# MYSQL in ember js

Tags: ember.js

```
<center>
<div>
    <h1 >Registration Page</h1>
    <form {{action "register" on="submit"}}>
        First Name{{input type="text" placeholder="First-Name" value=fname  required="true"}}<br/>
        Last Name{{input type="text" placeholder="Second-Name" value=lname required="true"}}<br/>
        E-mail{{input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" value=email required="true"}}<br/>
        Password{{input type="password" placeholder="Password" value=password required="true"}}<br/>
        Confirm-Password{{input type="password" placeholder="Retype password" value=confirmPassword required="true"}}<br/>
        <button >Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is my ember code.How can i push this form data into MYSQL database? and how to retrieve it again to diaplay?

Comment: Could you edit to format the example code within a code block? It'll be much easier for people to understand.

Comment: hoo sry i have edited the code now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several pieces to this question. There are also several solutions. My advice is to create a model for your Person or User. Then you can use the model hook on your router to pass it in.

```
export default
Model.extend({
    fName: attr('string'),
    lName: attr('string'),
    email: attr('string'), 
    password: attr('string') 
});
```

Then you can create a new model with the model hook in the route

```
model(){ 
    return store.createRecord('Person', {}); 
}
```

After you've done that, you can do something like this in your template

```
<center>
    <div>
        <h1 >Registration Page</h1>
            <form {{action "register" on="submit"}}>
                First Name{{input type="text" placeholder="First-Name" value=model.fname  required="true"}}
                Last Name{{input type="text" placeholder="Second-Name" value=model.lname required="true"}}
                E-mail{{input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" value=model.email required="true"}}
                Password{{input type="password" placeholder="Password" value=model.password required="true"}}
                Confirm-Password{{input type="password" placeholder="Retype password" value=model.confirmPassword required="true"}}
               <button >Send</button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Lastly, you'll need an action in your route to send that data to your server

```
register(model){
     model.save();
}
```

That's the part you handle in ember. After that, you need some sort of server to receive that data and store it into mysql. You can write that server in whatever you want, but you'll need that server to interact with your mysql db. Ember doesn't interact with the db directly.

Also, I highly recommend reading the Ember documentation. A lot of your questions will be answered there. There are also a ton of tutorials on the topic, so browse around and find something that suites your needs.

Ember has a fairly high learning curve to begin with, but (for me at least) it's well worth the payoff in the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.I am already able to store this data in the server.I will use ajax calls to create connection to the database and store it into my database.

Comment: It will probably make your life easier to use one of the built in adapters that ember has than to make custom ajax calls.

Comment: whenever i am storing data locally the record is not been saved  if i refresh the page the record is vanished.I have placed the "register(model){model.save}" in my controller. can please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: It sounds like your database isn't saving it properly. Have you checked your db for the records?

Comment: I am not connected to any database when i am seeing in ember inspector the record is there..but when i refresh the page the record shows with values as undefined .

Comment: The `store` in ember is only meant for temporary storage. When you do `model.save()` ember needs a backend service to make a call to for permanent storage. Ember alone will not permanently store anything. That's why it disappears after you refresh the page.

Comment: actually my controller is not executing i think.when i am clicking the send button it is going to router in that model hook is executed.but then it was not going to controller my register function is not executing.how i am saying this is i have added an alert box in controller it was not been displaying when i clicked send button.....

Comment: please can you explain me what is the flow after clicking the send button i am very confused.And can you tell me how to create a backend if it was not problem of my controller.

Comment: Assuming you have your view and controller hooked up correctly, when you hit the send button, the view sends the model to the controller, then the controller sends a the model to the backend, then the controller waits for a response from the backend on whether or not the save was successful. It then handles the response appropriately.

As for building a backend, that's a completely separate application you need write. I suggest reading about REST APIs. Ember expects a json-api. Check [this](http://jsonapi.org/) for exact specifications. Are you familiar with Node?

Comment: You can also use somthing like https://github.com/firebase/emberfire to help take care of the backend stuff for you.

Comment: I haven't used any view just i have a route with model hook and a controller with register function.Basically the route responsibility is to set the model on controller right.In the model we have "return"  statement for whom it is returning the person?.

Comment: You should have a view. The question you first posted about had the view contained in it. Though other than that, I think what you said is essentially correct.